# Socket with Delphi Android application

Tags: android, delphi, sockets, mobile, tclientsocket

I’m doing an Delphi Android application that which will receive the temperature from Arduino, I think do a sockets is a good way for to do this communication, but I’ve no idea how I can do a sockets with Delphi Android application, it’s different from Delphi for Windows. Can you help me about that? I’m using Delphi XE5.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi ships with Indy, which supports all of the platforms that Delphi supports.  Look at the `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` components as a starting point.  Indy works the same way on all platforms, so you can use the same code on Windows and Android.

Comment: Hello, Remy! Thank you for help me. Did you have some example how can I use that? I'm new in programming.

Comment: Ok, I'll try do that. Thank you for attention.